# Where is Codeigniter system's core file prefix that is 'CI'? How prefix work in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I learned from start that to use the same name of class as of file name. For that reason I started to look for '`CI_Controller`' file in my codeigniter that I usually extends. I found a controller file with a class named 'CI_Controller'. After research I found out that codeigniter is using prefix mechanism.

I tried to find out where codeigniter has declared 'CI' as its prefix but I was unable to find it?

One more the thing; how at backend this prefix mechanism works? Is it prefixed 'CI' with file name before compilation or it just keeps track of every class with respect to 'CI'?
This point is getting quite confusing for me.

Comment: As far as the core file(Not database files[.sql file]) coding is concerned, they written code with CI prefix. To implement in database files, they created a automatic mechanism to add prefix to database tables.

Comment: @Gunaseelan; You mean to say they first prefix 'CI' with the filenames and in coding they use classes with CI prefix. Can you please tell me where is that prefixing code in codeigniter that prefix 'CI' to filenames.

Comment: There is no function to create CI in classnames automatically. They written manually for filenames and its class names.